# Rewrite check_box_tag to f.checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How can I rewrite this check_box_tag to f.checkbox?

```
<%= check_box_tag("skill[course_ids][]", c.id, @skill.course_ids.include?(c.id), id: dom_id(c)) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***collection_check_boxes***](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) instead.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:course_ids, c.id, @skill.course_ids.include?(c.id), id: dom_id(c)) %>
```